# Podio Address bug?

Tags: php, podio

Here is a screenshot from an app that I have in podio. I am trying to set the address field via a php script. The following is how I set my fields.

```
$field->values = array(
        'value' => $latLong['address'],
        'lat' => $latLong['latitude'],
        'lng' => $latLong['longitude']
    );
```

From the item activity feed is shows that the address was updated. But when you look at the actual item, the address location is blank, but it has the right map location. Any ideas on what is causing this issue?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've had an occasional issue with updates where the actual field won't update until I refresh the page, even though the activity stream shows the update. Does refreshing change anything?

Comment: No refreshing the page doesn't do anything.. I thought it may also be because it may take podio time for update the item. But 16 hours later the address field has not updated. Its weird because the first few thousand records are correct. But the other 30k records are wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting value a bit differently :)

```
  addr_full = { 'street_address'  => 'some street address here',
                'postal_code'     => 'some zip code, eg: 90210',
                'city'            => 'Beverly Hills',
                'state'           => 'CA',
                'country'         => 'United States' }
```

Sorry, code is from Ruby but it shouldn't be hard to convert it to php syntax.

Comment: Pavlo saves the day again!!.. I guess things work when you use them like were designed